# What happened to this in PowerShell V3 CTP2 ISE?

Tags: powershell-3.0

In PowerShell V2 the following returns the Encoding of the current editor

```
$a=$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files[0]
$a.gettype().getfield("encoding","nonpublic,instance").getvalue($a)
```

and with

```
$a=$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files[0]
$a.gettype().getfield("encoding","nonpublic,instance").setvalue($a,[text.encoding]::ascii)
```

you can set the encoding to ASCII. cf. [this post](http://www.nivot.org/post/2010/05/21/PowerShellISEHackingChangeDefaultSaveEncodingToASCII.aspx)

Trying the same with PowerShell V3 fails. Obviously getfield() returns no object. Any ideas to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you use reflection to hack into non-public members of a class, you're running the risk it would break in a future release. That's what's happened here.

That said, try this:

```
$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files | % {
    $_.gettype().getfield("doc","nonpublic,instance").getvalue($_).Encoding = [text.encoding]::ascii
}
```

Or, to quote the whole script:

```
# watch for changes to the Files collection of the current Tab
register-objectevent $psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files collectionchanged -action {
    # iterate ISEFile objects
    $event.sender | % {
         # set encoding on private ITextDocument field to ASCII
         $_.gettype().getfield("doc","nonpublic,instance").getvalue($_).Encoding = [text.encoding]::ascii
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. Can you give a hint, how to list all the nonpublic members or is that worth another question?

Comment: dotPeek or justDecompile or reflector ... etc

Comment: or poke ;-)  github.com/oising/poke/

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it before (in v2) but looks like this is working in CTP2:

```
PS> $a = $psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files[0]
PS> $a.Encoding

BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001


PS> $a.Save([text.encoding]::ascii)
PS> $a.Encoding

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : us-ascii
EncodingName      : US-ASCII
HeaderName        : us-ascii
WebName           : us-ascii
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 20127
```